# Export static html including images, CSS, JS etc

Tags: plugin-development

For a client I need to export websites as static html (/w images, CSS, JS etc.), which I have created in Craft.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a plugin for this.

Can someone give me a hint, how do I start with this?

Answer (score 4):

I see 3 options, none of which warrant the creation of a plug-in:

1. - Get *Craft* to output all your URLs as a simple, unformatted list. Easy enough to do this with Twig templates, right (ask if not!)? Save this as `pages.txt`
   - Install `wget`. Simple to do on Linux (`apt-get install wget` probably), if you're on a Mac you can install it using `brew install wget`.
   - `wget -i pages.txt`
   - You should now have all the pages as lovely static `.html` files.
2. - Get *Craft* to output pages as a big `.json` data file. Again, easy enough to do with Twig templates.
   - Use a 'Static CMS' to read in this JSON and use it to build out a reproduction as a static website. Personally, I'd use *Middleman* or *Assemble.io* if I was doing this - but I guess it depends if you're more comfortable with Ruby or Node.js respectively.
3. Ask yourself why you're doing this? Is it performance? Security? Maybe if you get up to date with use of the `{% cache %}` tags you'll have a much easier time!

Comment: Thanks ianp for your quick post! The craft instance is to edit and create static landingpages. I need a user/editor friendly solution. I had play with wget, but there are some issues and inter alia because of this it is no solution for an editor.

Comment: No worries. I'm sorry I don't know what you mean by "inter alia"?

I don't understand why you can't just let Craft output the pages directly. Maybe if you could explain your setup a little clearer? I think you could rigger wget using Craft, which might make it a little 'editor friendly'-er.

Comment: Amongst others (sorry for my bad english).

Comment: np. My previous question still stands!